# How to stop mysql

Tags: mysql, macos

I run mysql.server stop

then

```
$ mysql.server stop
Shutting down MySQL
.. SUCCESS!
```

And mysql configuration is like this. It seems to be stopped.

[image]

However, I can run mysql -uroot

```
$ mysql -uroot
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8
Server version: 8.0.15 Homebrew

Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

What is happening ?
I guess that two mysql are installed because I used homebrew to install mysql. If so, how to stop another one ?

Comment: You don't need two servers, maybe uninstall one.

Comment: Check where the other one is installed, and call `stop` on that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. I once run `brew services start mysql`.

So, even if i run mysql.server stop, soon mysql server restarted.

I disabled auto restart by `brew services stop mysql`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make sure, you could always `ps` the MySQL process.
Also, you could check if the `port` to see if it's been occupied by the MySQL process.